# custom split view for read pages in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view, ipad

I am working on epub reader, i want to split views as image below,when user read above view also able to read below view.

please help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKn0Y.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny4oW.png

Comment: How about some code? Have you already tried to use multiple webviews?

Comment: Seems like something a lot of people can help you with - but what is your "problem"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this resources:

- http://www.mindtreatstudios.com/our-projects/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-ios/
- http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html